# TypeError: Cannot read property 'mv' of undefined in Node.js

Tags: node.js

My Node.js code:

```
app.use(fileUpload());

app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
  if (!req.files)
    return res.status(400).send('No files were uploaded.');

  // The name of the input field (i.e. "sampleFile") is used to retrieve the uploaded file
  console.log(req.files);
  let sampleFile = req.files[0];

  // Use the mv() method to place the file somewhere on your server
  sampleFile.mv('C:/Users/MNaaraayanan/Downloads/boilerplate_new/src/main/ngapp/', function(err) {
    if (err)
      return res.status(500).send(err);

    res.send('File uploaded!');
  });
});
```

The `console.log()`:

```
{ 'uploads[]':
   { name: 'blank_user.png',
     data: <Buffer 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52 00 00 00 fb 00 00 00 fb 08 02 00 00 00 23 10 75 f1 00 00 00 19 74 45 58 74 53 6f 66 74 77 61 72 65 00 ... >,
     encoding: '7bit',
     truncated: false,
     mimetype: 'image/png',
     md5: '0c803e9cef05aedeada6fb9587f1b073',
     mv: [Function: mv] } }
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'mv' of undefined
>           at C:\Users\MNaaraayanan\Downloads\boilerplate_new\src\main\ngapp\server.js:19:14
>           at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\MNaaraayanan\Downloads\boilerplate_new\src\main\ngapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>           at next (C:\Users\MNaaraayanan\Downloads\boilerplate_new\src\main\ngapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
>           at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\MNaaraayanan\Downloads\boilerplate_new\src\main\ngapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
>           at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\MNaaraayanan\Downloads\boilerplate_new\src\main\ngapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>           at C:\Users\MNaaraayanan\Downloads\boilerplate_new\src\main\ngapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
>           at Function.process_params (C:\Users\MNaaraayanan\Downloads\boilerplate_new\src\main\ngapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
>           at Busboy.next (C:\Users\MNaaraayanan\Downloads\boilerplate_new\src\main\ngapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
>           at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
>           at Busboy.emit (events.js:208:7)

the `req.file` contains the image but when I read the the `.mv()` function it is saying `undefined`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

following your console.log, I think the structure should be

```
let sampleFile = req.files['uploads[]'];
sampleFile.mv();
```

it looks like `req.files = { 'uploads[]': { mv } }` , not `req.files = [{ mv }]`

Answer (score 0):

use ***express-fileupload***

```
npm install express-fileupload
```

```
const fs = require('fs');
const app = express();
const fileUpload= require("express-fileupload");
app.use(fileUpload());

app.post('/upload/', (req, res, next) => {

  console.log(req.files); // To Check whether you received the file

  const file = req.files.xxxImage;
  const fileName = req.files.xxxImage.name;
  console.log(fileName);
  const  path = 'C:/Users/Project/client/public/Image/';

  // If you don't want to consider the error enable this line
  // file.mv(path + fileName);

  file.mv(path + fileName, function (err) {
    if (err) {
     return res.send(err);
    }else{
      res.send('File uploaded');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So i had the same problem and as per the error i was certain problem was in "mv", then i changed the code in form putting
name="file" and id="files" here's the code that solved the problem:-

```
<input type="file" className="form-control-file" name="file" id="files" multiple/>
```

you might also need to change proxy in your client side package.json just put this:-

```
"proxy":"http://localhost:4000/",
```

what it does is send the request to 4000 port when it could not find the route in port 3000(provided 4000 is server side and 3000 is front end part)

Answer (score -1):

Here you need to assign the name of the file that given in the name attribute of the view engine or html input element

```
let sampleFile = req.files.attributename[0];
```