# Nodejs forEach over req.files

Tags: node.js, loops, object, iteration

I have trouble iterating over `req.files`

How can i iterate over files0, files1 and ....

In my components:

```
 for (let i = 0; i < this.selectedFile.length; i++) {
    files.append(`files${i}`, this.selectedFile[i]);
  }
```

In node file:

```
    let file =  req.files.files0
    return file.mv('./uploads/'+file.name)
```

And when i log req.files i have code below:
it is an object including objects in it

```
    [Object: null prototype] {                                                                                                        
     files0: {
     name: 'Cakkkpture.PNG',
     data: <Buffer >,
     size: 28219,
     encoding: '7bit',
     tempFilePath: '\\tmp\\tmp-4-1648625334268',
     truncated: false,
     mv: [Function: mv]
    }
   }
```

For more details:

Actually i am using `express-fileupload` libarary to access `req.files` default value it makes an object b default and i am making another object as child for it by appending data:

```
  let files = new FormData(); 
  for (let i = 0; i < this.selectedFile.length; i++) {
    files.append(`files${i}`, this.selectedFile[i]);
  }
```

it will make something like this for `req.files`

```
req.files: {
    files0: {
  },
   files1: {
  }
}
```

And more files${i} as the user enters
This loop is for creating files that the user uploads
Now with the code above it will just generate one file but I want it to generate multiple files

Comment: can you add more code? Are you able to see files in req.files? If not you might need to handle the multi-part data.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara sure
i will edit my post

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara i have changed it it would be great if can help me

Comment: If you see `req.files`, it is an object, not an array. Can you show me the full code how are you adding the files? It seems only one file is added.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara i have edited my question again i hope it would be clear right now

Comment: It seems that `req.files` is an `Object`. If one needs to access each of the `prop`s (or `key`s) within the object, one is able to use `Object.keys(objName)` which provides an array of keys. So, if one tries: `Object.keys(req.files).forEach(k => console.log('key is: ,k));` - one should get a list of keys such as `file0, file1, ...`. Please try it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this as `req.files` is an object we can iterate over it using keys.

```
for (const file in req?.files) {
    console.log(req.files[file]);
}
```

Note: instead of for loop use `for in` loop.

Comment: thanks it worked but i am getting this error `file.mv('./uploads/'+file.name)`  do know what is wrong with it? 
mv is a build in function in `express-uploadfile` library

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: `message: "file.mv is not a function"`

Comment: check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49916044/typeerror-cannot-read-property-mv-of-undefined-in-node-js)